# Express.js Type Error When Importing DB Schema

Tags: node.js, express, mean-stack

Creating a small web app on the MEAN stack and I'm in the process of migrating my schemas to a separate "models" directory.  When the schemas are defined in the same **app.js** file, everything works fine; however, when I switch the code to a separate more modular file and import it I get this error:

```
TypeError: Player.find is not a function
at /Users/username/code/express/WebApp/v3/app.js:57:12
```

This error occurs when it gets to that first route where it needs to look players up and I'm not quite sure what I'm missing after staring at this for hours.

My app.js file:

```
var express    = require("express"),
    app        = express(),
    bodyParser = require("body-parser"),
    mongoose   = require("mongoose"),
    Player     = require("./models/players")

const port     = 3000;

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/players", { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));


// PLAYER SCHEMA ORIGNALLY DEFINED HERE BUT NOW ATTEMPTING TO MOVE TO DIFF DIRECTORY & IMPORT
/*var playerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    player: String,
    position: String,
    description: String
});
var Player = mongoose.model("Player", playerSchema);*/

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    res.render("landing");
});

app.get("/players", function(req, res) {
    // Get all players from DB
    Player.find({}, function(err, allPlayers){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log("We're good.");
            res.render("players", {players: allPlayers});        
        }
    });
});
```

and my player.js file that I'm attempting to import:

```
var mongoose   = require("mongoose");

var playerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    player: String,
    position: String,
    description: String
});


// Compile into a model
module.exports = mongoose.model("Player", playerSchema);
```

The above schema definition and model definition work completely fine when they're in the app.js file, but not when imported.  What am I missing here?  Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your file name is wrong at the require statement. Its

```
const Player = require('../models/player')
```

as your file name is player.js, not players.js and if you stored the js file in a model folder. Do check out how to navigate using the file path

/ means go back to the root folder, then traverse forward/downward.

./ means begin in the folder we are currently in and traverse forward/downward

../ means go up one directory, then begin the traverse.

And also your backend should look like this.
[Backend File Management](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPxzo.png)

Comment: Forgive me, that should've read as plural with an 'S' at the end and was not the issue.  That being said, your second suggestion was correct.  My models directory was not where I thought it was and the references to it turned out to be the issue.